# Running latest unstable nodejs (e.g. 0.11.6) on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, ecmascript-harmony

I've not been having much luck finding an answer to this:

What is the simplest way to install/run the latest bleeding edge version of nodejs on heroku for an existing application?

There is the use of package.json engines as described here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support

But this does not cover the latest unstable 0.11.x branch which is the one I'm after.

Comment: Did you try simply writing the version number?

Comment: They don't support it as documented (http://heroku-buildpack-nodejs.s3.amazonaws.com/manifest.nodejs). You'll need to look at other solutions: http://arunoda.me/blog/official-nodejs-binaries-on-heroku.html

Comment: @raam86 - how would that help?

Comment: In the config file.....

Comment: @raam86 --I did try 0.11.6 in the package.json as per documentation and it simply installed the latest STABLE 0.10.x release.

Comment: @WiredPrairie - thanks for the link to arunoda.me. This does seem to install 0.11.6 but then runs into a gyp compile error when building the app.

Comment: Again, Heroku doesn't really fully support an unstable version (not surprisingly), so maybe you'll just need to patiently wait ... :)

Answer (score 2):

### **Edit: as of 2013-12-12 the [default buildpack can vendor any version of nodejs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version)**

Just specify the version you want in your `package.json`, e.g.

```
"engines": {
    "node": "0.11.x"
}
```

**Old:**

I alomost wrote a buildback myself, but then found this one that vendors node binaries from nodejs.org:
https://github.com/arunoda/heroku-nodejs-binary-buildback

The instructions are simple, just don't forget to config:set NODE_VERSION.

**YMMV**: for me 0.11.7 caused NPM to fail to verify package checksums, but 0.11.6 works just fine.